# PDF object not showing when HTML file is opened from visual studio

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio

I have an HTML file that I am tinkering with attempting create a web form with functionality and have a PDF view embeded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head>
<body>
<object data="C:\test\PI.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

The PDF **works fine** when I open it from windows explorer or sublime text. It will have a URL in the browser that looks like this:

file:///C:/Users/dvandenbosch/Desktop/Visual%20Studio%20And%20General%20Programming/temp/scratchpad.html

When I open it from visual studio, it **doesn't allow me to see the pdf**. It is just blank. It has a URL that looks like this.

http://localhost:59478/scratchpad.html

Why is this?
I need to be able to show pdfs from my shared file drive on to our internal sharepoint using a web browser. Please help!

Comment: pdf with .html extension?

Comment: The pdf is embedded in the html file.